# pthread_t on mac os x is NULL

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

i'm using this code on AIX/HP-UX/LINUX, but when i try to run it on Mac os x it dont work well:

```
pthread_t m_thread;
                int merror;//thread return
cout << "init" << endl;
                if (m_thread != NULL){
 cout << "running" << endl;
 merror= pthread_create(&m_thread, NULL, _exec, NULL);//initialize thread
}
```

On linux the pthread is created and the running message appears on the screen.
But on Mac os x the m_thread returns null, so o can't execute the same code on MAC OS X, someone know why it's happening.

The compiling code: g++ -g -o sclient sclient.cpp socket.cpp -pthread -lpthread -thread

Comment: Hate to say it, but your code works for me with no NULL return (MacOS 10.7.3)

Comment: Are you getting an error, or not? And what does your code do after `pthread_create` returns? (If you end the process, the thread may not get a chance to run.)

Comment: Solved, i dont know why on linux the test returns its okay, so i removed the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't check `m_thread != NULL`, it makes no sense. Remove that check and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `m_thread` when you make the test - it's value is indeterminate.